# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. In GetResponse()

Tags: c#, mandrill

I am trying to call a HTML page from Mandrill. The HTML below is not being displayed in console.
//HTML Template I am calling

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<tr>
    <td>This is a test email from Mandrill</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

//Console app

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var request = 
      WebRequest.Create("https://mandrillapp.com/templates/preview?id=test-email") as   HttpWebRequest;
      request.Method = "POST";
      request.ContentType = "text/plain";
      byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("");
      request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

      using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
      {
         postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
      }

      using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
      {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
           string value = reader.ReadToEnd();
           Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you expected anything else? Your code looks ok, and likely server you are trying to hit is not expecting such requests. (Side note url looks more like SMTP endpoint rather than HTTP).

Answer (score 0):

That is because the web page does not exist. You would get the same result if if tried to open it in a browser (unless it responds to a GET but not a POST) -- I just tried it myself to confirm, it is giving an http 404 error at the address you supply.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to access - http://smtp.mandrillapp.com/test-email - is an API Endpoint. According to the docs here - http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24486133-Does-Mandrill-have-a-test-mode-or-sandbox- you will need to [generate a new Test API Key](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24486133-Does-Mandrill-have-a-test-mode-or-sandbox-#test_key) for testing emails and then authenticate your access in your C# code before attempting to post to that endpoint.